# How to view samples from ImageDataGenerator()

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am currently working through a tutorial which is using the cifar10 images. I have written some fully working code which has the line `model.fit(x_train, y_train)` where x_train as a numpy array of dimension 50000x32x32x3 and dtype "uint8". I.e. it contains 50000 32x32 pixel colour images. I can display a sample of these images with calls to imshow() - it all looks and works fine.

But now in the next part of the tutorial it suggests that the model will generalise better if we use ImageDataGenerator() to create multiple warped (rotated, zoomed, sheered etc) versions of our training images. I want to better understand ImageDataGenerator() by displaying some of the warped images that are produced in the process. Looking at [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator), it gives the following example:

```
# here's a more "manual" example
for e in range(epochs):
    print('Epoch', e)
    batches = 0
    for x_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32):
        model.fit(x_batch, y_batch)
        batches += 1
        if batches >= len(x_train) / 32:
            # we need to break the loop by hand because
            # the generator loops indefinitely
            break
```

My current code (without warping) trains the model with the line `model.fit(x_train, y_train)`, so looking at the line in the example `model.fit(x_batch, y_batch)` I assume that x_batch must be a collection of 32 different warped versions of the current x_train image. I tried to write some code so that I could actually display the 32 images like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def print_array_info(v):
    print("{} is of type {} with shape {} and dtype {}".format(v,
                                                           eval("type({})".format(v)),
                                                           eval("{}.shape".format(v)),
                                                           eval("{}.dtype".format(v))
                                                           ))

def show_samples(array_of_images):
    n = array_of_images.shape[0]
    total_rows = 1+int((n-1)/5)
    total_columns = 5
    fig = plt.figure()
    gridspec_array = fig.add_gridspec(total_rows, total_columns)

    for i, img in enumerate(array_of_images):
        row = int(i/5)
        col = i % 5
        ax = fig.add_subplot(gridspec_array[row, col])
        ax.imshow(img)

    plt.show()


cifar_data = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar_data.load_data()

data_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20)

print_array_info("x_train")

batches = 0
batch_size=32

for x_batch, y_batch in data_generator.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size):
    print_array_info("x_batch")
    batches += 1
    if batches >= len(x_train) / 32:
        break
    show_samples(x_batch[:batch_size])
```

I thought that the first time through the loop I would be shown 32 different warped versions of the zeroth image in x_train. But when I run this it produces almost blank images - I say almost because one or to of them may contain a few garbage looking pixels. I expected x_batch to be of size 32x32x32x3, i.e. a collection of 32 colour images of size 32x32pixels and 3 colours which indeed appears true but the dtype was float32 which confuses me - I thought the warping process would not change the dtype.

Have I got a bug in my code or have I misunderstood the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x_batch` is an array of float type because of random rotation applied to the dataset.

When image data (`x_batch`) passed to [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html?highlight=imshow#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow) is of `float` type, rgb-values have to be within range from `0`-`1`. Multiply `x_batch` by `1/225` to get unit fraction representation.

```py
for x_batch, y_batch in data_generator.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size):
    print_array_info("x_batch")
    batches += 1
    if batches >= len(x_train) / batch_size:
        break
    show_samples(x_batch * 1 / 255)
```